# Calculate time complexity of Ruby Array#uniq own implementation

Tags: ruby, arrays, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I saw [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36027/implementing-arrayuniq-in-ruby).

I did this with different arguments:

```
def uniq(arr)
  out = {}
  arr.each do |el|
    out[el] = nil
  end
  out.keys
end
```

What is the tie complexity of this code and how can I improve it?

## Update

What about:

```
def uniq(arr)
  arr | []
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity of your function is O(n) because the work it needs to do is linearly proportional to the size of the array.

You've got two loops `arr.each`, and `out.keys`. The complexity of each is **O(n)** since the complexity of each loop body is **O(1)** (i.e. the work that needs to be done inside the loop body is independent of the array size). Since the two loops are independent of each other the total complexity is **O(n)**.

Your second function also has time complexity O(n). It will convert the array into a set to get rid of duplicates and then convert it back into an array. To convert it into a set it will first loop over the contents of the array with a time complexity O(n); each iteration will insert an item into the set. Inserting items into ruby Sets has the time complexity O(1) (a Set is implemented using a Hash and hashes typically have constant time insertion). Converting the final set back into an array requires another loop. Again this loop has time complexity O(n). The two loops, `arr -> set` and `set -> arr` are independent of each other and so the final time complexity is O(n).

I suggest you read about time complexity:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: but to call `keys` and `[]=` means `n` complexity so it is: `n * n + n` isn't it?

Comment: The complexity of `out.keys` is also n, and so is it for `arr.each` but those two loops are independent of each other so the total complexity is still O(n). The time complexity  for `[]=` is O(1), i.e. it's a constant independent of the key or the value in the assignment.